# Redirecting stdout of a simple PyQt5 application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following super simple qt application:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

print('hello \n')
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

When executing it normally with terminal hello message is shown, h/w when redirecting stdout to a file:

```
python3 qt_redirect.py > file.txt
```

the file remains empty.

Help me guys, what am I missing here?

python version - 3.6.9
PyQt5 version - 5.14.1
os - ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to clean the buffer when printing and for this there are several options:

- flush=True

```
print('hello \n'. flush=True)
```

- Set the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable to "1":

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python3 qt_redirect.py > file.txt
```

- User the python "-u" option:

```
python3 -u  qt_redirect.py > file.txt
```